# Spring error : BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

My controller contains the following annotation :

```
@Resource(name="userService")
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userService;
```

and the service itself has the following :

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

However I receive the following error on startup :

> Injection of resource dependencies
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException:
>   Bean named 'userDetailsServiceImpl'
>   must be of type
>   [myapp.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl], but was actually of
>   type [$Proxy19]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be

```
@Resource(name="userService")
private UserDetailsService userService;
```

Spring uses the interface type to make dependency injection, not the implementation type

Comment: What if someone wants to use getters or setters which may not be defined in the interface?

Answer (score 4):

Change to (interface instead of concrete class):

```
@Resource(name="userService")
private UserDetailsService userService;
```

And live happily ever after.

Long version: at runtime, by default, Spring replaces your class with *something* that implements all the interfaces of your class. If you inject interface rather than a concrete type, you don't care what is the exact type implementing this interface.

In your case adding `@Transactional` annotation causes your bean to be replaced by AOP proxy with transaction capabilities. If you remove this annotation, your code will run fine. However, it is a good idea to depend on interfaces, not on concrete implementations.